# Filter over arrays and return a search input

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, filter, push

I am trying to filter through an array of an array of strings and want to push all instances of an array that includes a search term into its own array.

I've tried to use the map, filter, forEach helper methods, but just can't seem to get the search input to do what I'm trying to get it to do.

I'm trying to do this without using a traditional "for" loop for simplicity.

```
const booksArray = [
  [
    'The City We Became',
    'N. K. Jemisin',
    'fantasy',
    'fiction',
    'afrofutursim',
   'science fiction',
    'sci-fi'
  ],
  [
    'The Catcher in the Rye',
    'J. D. Salinger',
    'fiction',
    'young adult',
    'YA',
    'realism',
    'coming of age',
    'classic'
  ],
  [
    'The Hundred Thousand Kingdoms',
    'N. K. Jemisin',
    'fantasy',
    'fiction',
    'adventure',
    'series'
  ],
  [
    'Sapiens: A Brief History of Humankind',
    'Yuval Noah Harari',
    'nonfiction',
    'history',
    'anthropology',
    'science',
    'sociology'
  ],
  [
    'Behave: The Biology of Humans at Our Best and Worst',
    'Robert M. Sapolsky',
    'nonfiction',
    'anthropology',
    'science',
    'sociology',
    'biology'
  ],
  [
    'The Parable of the Talents',
    'Octavia Butler',
    'fiction',
    'dystopian',
    'science fiction'
  ],
  [
    '1984',
    'George Orwell',
    'fiction',
    'dystopian',
    'science fiction',
    'classics',
    'adult'
  ],
  [
    'Remarkably Bright Creatures',
    'Shelby Van Pelt',
    'fiction',
    'mystery',
    'magical realism'
  ],
  [
    'Crying in H Mart',
    'Michelle Zauner',
    'memoir',
    'nonfiction',
    'autobiography'
  ],
  [
    'Wild: From Lost to Found on the Pacific Crest Trail',
    'Cheryl Strayed',
    'nonfiction',
    'memoir',
    'adventure',
   'travel'
  ]
]

  const filterBooks = (searchInput) => { 
    let filteredBooks = []
    booksArray.filter(searchInput) 
        filteredBooks.push(booksArray)
  };


  console.log(filterBooks('fantasy')) 

// Uncaught TypeError: string "fantasy" is not a function
   at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at filterBooks (index.js:72:16)
    at index.js:78:15
```

Comment: `Array.filter()` takes a function; you are passing a string, `'fantasy'` Additionally, `Array.filter()` returns a new array, so you would be pushing the original `booksArray` into `filteredBooks`.

Comment: Don't use an array for each book. Use an object so you can name the fields, e.g. `{title: "Sapiense: A Brief History of Humankind", author: "Yuval Noah Harari", genres: ['nonfiction', 'history', 'anthropology', ...]}`

Comment: @Barmar naming the fields seems to complicate it since I want the search input to be able to filter based off of each .. how would you recommend that be done?  Maybe I’m missing something?

Comment: `.filter(book => book.title.includes(searchInput) || book.author.includes(searchInput) || book.genres.includes(searchInput))`

Comment: @Barmar I can’t believe I forgot about the “or” operator .. thanks for the help and clarifying

Answer (score 0):

The filter method was not used correctly. The filter method expects a callback function that should return true or false based on a specific condition. However, in the code provided, you passed searchInput directly to the filter method, which doesn't make sense.

You did not return the result of the filterBooks function. So when you try to print the result using console.log, it will print undefined as the function does not have an explicit return value.

Code adjusted:

```
const booksArray = [
  [
    'The City We Became',
    'N. K. Jemisin',
    'fantasy',
    'fiction',
    'afrofutursim',
   'science fiction',
    'sci-fi'
  ],
  [
    'The Catcher in the Rye',
    'J. D. Salinger',
    'fiction',
    'young adult',
    'YA',
    'realism',
    'coming of age',
    'classic'
  ],
  [
    'The Hundred Thousand Kingdoms',
    'N. K. Jemisin',
    'fantasy',
    'fiction',
    'adventure',
    'series'
  ],
  [
    'Sapiens: A Brief History of Humankind',
    'Yuval Noah Harari',
    'nonfiction',
    'history',
    'anthropology',
    'science',
    'sociology'
  ],
  [
    'Behave: The Biology of Humans at Our Best and Worst',
    'Robert M. Sapolsky',
    'nonfiction',
    'anthropology',
    'science',
    'sociology',
    'biology'
  ],
  [
    'The Parable of the Talents',
    'Octavia Butler',
    'fiction',
    'dystopian',
    'science fiction'
  ],
  [
    '1984',
    'George Orwell',
    'fiction',
    'dystopian',
    'science fiction',
    'classics',
    'adult'
  ],
  [
    'Remarkably Bright Creatures',
    'Shelby Van Pelt',
    'fiction',
    'mystery',
    'magical realism'
  ],
  [
    'Crying in H Mart',
    'Michelle Zauner',
    'memoir',
    'nonfiction',
    'autobiography'
  ],
  [
    'Wild: From Lost to Found on the Pacific Crest Trail',
    'Cheryl Strayed',
    'nonfiction',
    'memoir',
    'adventure',
   'travel'
  ]
]

const filterBooks = (searchInput) => { 
  const filteredBooks = booksArray.filter((book) => {
    return book.slice(2).includes(searchInput);
  });

  return filteredBooks;
};

console.log(filterBooks('fantasy'));
```